# Python/ Sudoku solver/ Method works incorrect

Tags: python, sudoku

I am trying to implement a sudoku solver in Python and one of my methods does not work correctly even though it is pretty simple and short. There is one `sudoku_grid` (zero means box is empty) in my code and one `possibility_arrays` list which contains possible numbers for each box. So this problematic method is `change_value(row, column, value)` which simply changes the value for one box once it is found and removes this particular number from other possiblity arrays in the same box, column and grid.

Here is the code (i only put related parts -there is other methods which simply applies different elimination techniques-i did some tracking and found problem lies in this method for some reason-:

```
    sudoku_grid = [
        [4, 2, 9, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0],
        [8, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 6],
        [0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0],
        [7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [9, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1],
        [2, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0],
        [6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0, 7]
    ]
    possibility_arrays = []
    for _ in range(9):
        possibility_arrays.append([])
    for s in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            possibility_arrays[x].append([])

    def is_valid(row, column, num):
        # Check if the number already exists in the row
        if num in sudoku_grid[row]:
            return False

        # Check if the number already exists in the column
        for i in range(9):
            if sudoku_grid[i][column] == num:
                return False

        # Check if the number already exists in the 3x3 grid
        start_row = (row // 3) * 3
        start_col = (column // 3) * 3
        for a in range(start_row, start_row + 3):
            for b in range(start_col, start_col + 3):
                if sudoku_grid[a][b] == num:
                    return False

        return True

    def change_value(row, column, value):

        if is_valid(row,column,value):
            sudoku_grid[row][column] = value
            possibility_arrays[row][column] = []

            for k in range(9):
                if value in possibility_arrays[k][column]:
                    possibility_arrays[k][column].remove(value)
                if value in possibility_arrays[row][k]:
                    possibility_arrays[row][k].remove(value)

            start_row = (row // 3) * 3
            start_col = (column // 3) * 3
            for a in range(start_row, start_row + 3):
                for b in range(start_col, start_col + 3):
                    if value in possibility_arrays[a][b]:
                        possibility_arrays[a][b].remove(value)
        else:
            print("THERE IS A MISTAKE")
```

And here is the `possibility_arrays` after some elimination process:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [1], [8], [5]],
[[], [], [], [], [4, 5], [4, 5], [], [6], [2]],
[[], [], [], [], [], [4, 8], [], [7, 8], [4]],
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
[[], [], [], [], [2, 4], [2, 4], [], [], [3]],
[[], [], [], [], [], [6], [], [], []],
[[], [], [], [], [2, 6], [2, 6], [], [], []],
[[], [], [], [3], [8], [1], [], [], []],
[[], [], [], [], [5], [], [], [], []],
```

And when i put the code `change_value(5, 5, possibility_array[5][5][0])` it simply removes 6 as expected from `possibility_array[6][5]` since it is in the same column but also removes 6 from `possibility_arrays[6][4]` and turns into this:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [1], [8], [5]]
[[], [], [], [], [4, 5], [4, 5], [], [6], [2]]
[[], [], [], [], [], [4, 8], [], [7, 8], [4]]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [2, 4], [2, 4], [], [], [3]]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [2], [2], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [3], [8], [1], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [5], [], [], [], []]
```

I have no idea how it sometimes works incorrect and works totally fine. As i said i only put this line (`change_value(5, 5, possibility_array[5][5][0])`) between these two states. And arrays are not related to each other, they are individual. Why this might happen?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. If I set `possibility_arrays` to the example you gave and run `change_value(5, 5, possibility_array[5][5])`, then 6 is not eliminated from `possibility_array[6][5]`.

Comment: `possibility_array[5][5]` is `[6]`, so `change_value(5, 5, possibility_array[5][5])` is same as `change_value(5, 5, [6])` which doesn't look right.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: @MichaelButscher yeah my bad, I edited in my question now. I just miswrote in my question, it was in the corrected way in my code before as well. So the problem is the same still.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i tried as much as I can, but somehow I'm not good with debugger so might be missing something.

Comment: @BoppreH yes when I test these parts in another code space, it works fine. But somehow when I use it in my main project it does not and I dont know why since there is no method that modifies change_value and i just put change_value(5, 5, possibility_arrays[5][5][0] between these two states. So I have no idea what may cause this.

Comment: Then you really have to provide a minimal example that shows the error, I haven't been able to reproduce it at all.

Comment: @BoppreH that is the exact error I get. As I said for some reason, it only occurs when I use those with my other methods, which does not modify change_value method. So I asked maybe someone can tell me some general things I may need to check. Otherwise I do not know how to get help since it would not be the best to share 300+ lines of code here and expect a help. I don't know.

Comment: I found how to fix, and posted. Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out change_value method was not the problem. Apperantly, in one of my other methods that I implement sudoku solving techniques (hidden_pairs), I typed a code which simply says

```
possibility_arrays[i][j] = mutual_array
possibility_arrays[i][k] = mutual_array
```

And this was somehow causing the problem, I guess. When I edited as this, the problem was fixed:

```
possibility_arrays[i][j] = mutual_array.copy()
possibility_arrays[i][k] = mutual_array.copy()
```

I thought change_value was the problem since it was removing 2 values at the same time, but now I assume it was the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If there's something wrong with your code, it's not shown here. Continuously propagating values with `change_value` solved the puzzle just fine:

```py
# Setup possibility_array with correct values for starting state.
for row in range(9):
    for col in range(9):
        possibility_arrays[row][col].extend(range(1, 10))
for row in range(9):
    for col in range(9):
        value = sudoku_grid[row][col]
        if value > 0:
            # Hacky way of propagating changes without failing the is_valid check.
            sudoku_grid[row][col] = 0
            change_value(row, col, value)

# Continuosly propagate cells with a single possibility.
progress = True
while progress:
    progress = False
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            if len(possibility_arrays[row][col]) == 1:
                change_value(row, col, possibility_arrays[row][col][0])
                progress = True

# We either solved the puzzle, or have to guess.
from pprint import pprint
pprint(sudoku_grid)
```

```
[[4, 2, 9, 6, 7, 3, 1, 8, 5],
 [3, 7, 8, 1, 4, 5, 9, 6, 2],
 [5, 6, 1, 2, 9, 8, 3, 7, 4],
 [8, 3, 2, 5, 1, 7, 4, 9, 6],
 [1, 9, 6, 8, 2, 4, 7, 5, 3],
 [7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 6, 2, 1, 8],
 [9, 8, 4, 7, 6, 2, 5, 3, 1],
 [2, 5, 7, 3, 8, 1, 6, 4, 9],
 [6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 2, 7]]
```